# Error installing zos-lib@2.4.0

Tags: nodejs, openzeppelin-contracts, openzeppelin-sdk

I am working through the tutorial for zeppelin-os found here: https://docs.zeppelinos.org/docs/linking.html

and have an error when running zos create

> Could not find file zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol in the project
>   (imported from contracts/TokenExchange.sol)

I thought it would be an error with the install of zos-lib@2.4.0 so tried to install it again, and received the following errors

> ryan@LAPTOP-SBSEC33S:~/token-exchange$ sudo npm install zos-lib@2.4.0 
>   npm WARN deprecated lodash.isarray@4.0.0: This package is deprecated.
>   Use Array.isArray.
>   npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with
>   Promise Support
>   npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has
>   been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar
>   module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
>
> > scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /home/ryan/token-exchange/node_modules/scrypt
> >     node node-scrypt-preinstall.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              > scrypt@6.0.3 install /home/ryan/token-exchange/node_modules/scrypt> node-gyp rebuild
> >     gyp ERR! configure error
> >     gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
> >     '/home/ryan/token-exchange/node_modules/scrypt/build'
> >     gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
> >     gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node"
> >     "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> >     "rebuild"                              gyp ERR! cwd
> >     /home/ryan/token-exchange/node_modules/scrypt
> >     gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
> >     gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> >     gyp ERR! not ok
> >     npm WARN token-exchange@1.0.0 No description
> >     npm WARN token-exchange@1.0.0 No repository field.
> >     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> >     npm ERR! errno 1
> >     npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> >     npm ERR! Exit status 1
> >     npm ERR!
> >     npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
> >     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> >     additional logging output above.
> >     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> >     npm ERR!     /home/ryan/.npm/_logs/2019-06-29T04_11_35_411Z-debug.log

It is not clear to me how to fix it in order to progress further in the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are having issues with node/npm rather than anything specific to ZeppelinOS.

You could delete the `token-exchange` directory and start the tutorial again.

I am not sure why you need to use `sudo`.

If you are not already, you could reinstall npm with a node version manager. https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

I use `nvm` successfully on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Please note if changing node versions, there is an issue using node 12 (https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/node-12-issue-with-truffle/808) so you need to use either node 10 or 11.

For questions regards ZeppelinOS and smart contract development you can ask in the community forum: https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/